# Loading specified key-values into a json object from dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary, parsing

I am looking to load a dictionary into a json object, but not all keys and values.

Example dictionary:

```
full_dict = {
            'code': 1,
            'length': 20,
            'height': 45,
            'name':"book"
        }
```

I want to make this a json object, and I've used

```
json.dumps(full_dict)
```

But I want to upload only selected fields from that dictionary, as in these fields only:

```
part_dict = {
            'length':20,
            'height':45,
            'name':"book"
        }
```

Summed up, I am looking to use:

```
json.dumps(full_dict)
```

And expect the following json object:

```
{"length": 20, "height": 45, "name": "book"}
```

Thank you, appreciate your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter the dictionary before you write it to disk:

```
full_dict = {
            'code': 1,
            'length': 20,
            'height': 45,
            'name':"book"
        }

keep = ['length', 'height', 'name']

partial_dict = {k: v for k, v in full_dict.items() if k in keep}
print(partial_dict)
```

If there's many fields, turning the keep into a dictionary for O(1) lookups instead is an easy optimization.

Answer (score 2):

I'd just always keep a list of keys you want to keep, or discard, or any other way of determining what keys you want.

Then just filter the dictionary and create a new one to save (encapsulate it as a function to reuse the code):

```
keys_to_keep = {'length', 'height', 'name'}

part_dict = {key: value for (key: value) in full_dict.items() if key in keys_to_keep}
json.dumps(part_dict)
```

`dict.items()` yields key and value pairs you can iterate, `keys_to_keep` is a set so that `in` is checked in `O(1)` (other answers that appeared while writing this all use lists which check `in` in `O(n)`!).

Answer (score 1):

Python 3.6

```
exclusion_list = ['code']
json.dumps({x:y for x,y in full_dict.items() if x not in exclusion_list)
```

or

```
inclusion_list = ['height', 'length', 'name']
json.dumps({x:y for x,y in full_dict.items() if x in inclusion_list )
```

Answer (score 1):

You may filter the keys

```py
import json

full_dict = {
    'code': 1,
    'length': 20,
    'height': 45,
    'name':"book"
}

filtered = dict([(k, v) for k, v in full_dict.items() if k in ['length', 'height', 'name']])

print(json.dumps(filtered))
```

> {"length": 20, "height": 45, "name": "book"}

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom `JSONEncoder` class with a overriden `encode` method to `pop` out the `code` key from the input `dict`:

```
class CustomJSONEncoder(json.JSONEncoder): 
    def encode(self, input_obj): 
        if isinstance(input_obj, dict): 
            _ = input_obj.pop('code', None) 
        return super().encode(input_obj)
```

**Example:**

```
In [837]: class CustomJSONEncoder(json.JSONEncoder): 
     ...:     def encode(self, input_obj): 
     ...:         if isinstance(input_obj, dict): 
     ...:             _ = input_obj.pop('code', None) 
     ...:         return super().encode(input_obj) 
     ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                   

In [838]: full_dict = { 
     ...:             'code': 1, 
     ...:             'length': 20, 
     ...:             'height': 45, 
     ...:             'name':"book" 
     ...:         }                                                                                                                                                                                         

In [839]: json.dumps(full_dict, cls=CustomJSONEncoder)                                                                                                                                                      
Out[839]: '{"length": 20, "height": 45, "name": "book"}'
```

As shown, pass the encoder class as `cls` argument to `json.dumps`.